# Theming Drupal book hierarchies

Tags: drupal

I'm just getting round to converting our static HTML website to Drupal. Our website is currently structured into sections, each section having a header, then a list of sub-sections below (for an example see http://www.eurosafeuk.co.uk/services/).

This ties in very nicely with Drupal's "book" module, but I need to customise the display of child pages; by default they're printed as an unordered list of page titles, whereas what I need is to output:

- A teaser image for each page
- The page title
- The page summary

I've looked through the .tpl files, and found that the children are stored in a $tree variable (already HTML formatted). My question is: where do I start if I want to modify this? Does anyone know of a pre-existing module that would do it, or do I need to dig into the code?

Comment: Whatever you do, it's wise to "do like Drupal" and override or hook into an existing module instead of changing a module yourself, which forces you to re-change any new versions of it. In most cases it's easier and safer to alter the existing behaviour of a module by writing your own module than by changing an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Book module which is specifically for a book structure, you might want to look into modules that are made for your case. I haven't looked very well but the [Node Hierarchy](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy) module might be useful for you. . Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... allows nodes to be children of other nodes creating a tree-like hierarchy of content. The module offers:
>
> - 1-Click creation of hierarchical menus
> - Hierarchical breadcrumbs
> - Automatic hierarchical urls using Pathauto (and token module)
>   (eg: q=aboutus/history/beginning).
> - Automatic creation of hierarchical menus if desired.
> - Optional Views integration.
> - Optional Node Access integration.

If you want to theme nodes in specific sections in different ways, it's probably a good idea to make separate .tpl files for every section. The way you name those .tpl files makes them *applicable* to nodes in a certain section.

Comment: I've been meaning to look at http://drupal.org/project/menu_block, which looks to be a lighter-weight approach to the same sort of idea.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, and turn on theme developer. This will tell you the template or function which is used to build the HTML and what templates you can create to override it.